# Xeditable form is saving form without even displaying it

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am trying to create an xeditable form as demonstrated here: https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form.

I have followed the instructions exactly but my form is not working. I want to save a resource, but when I click the Edit button, which should display the form, it seems to skip the editing stage and immediately triggers the saveResource function - which should only happen when the form gets *saved*.

I've compared my code to the documentation again and again and can't work out what I am doing wrong.

HTML

```
  <form editable-form name="editResourceForm" onaftersave="saveResource()">
    <p>
      <strong editable-text="resource.title" e-name="title">
        {{resource.title}}
      </strong>
    </p>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <button ng-click="editResourceForm.$show()" ng-show="!editResourceForm.$visible">Edit</button>
      <!-- buttons to submit / cancel form -->
      <span ng-show="editResourceForm.$visible">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="editResourceForm.$waiting">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="editResourceForm.$waiting" ng-click="editResourceForm.$cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

JS

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.resource = {
    title: 'awesome resource'
  };

  $scope.saveResource = function() {
    console.log("Save resource");
  }

});
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/15363/)

You can see that it is trying to save the form, because every time the Edit button is clicked, the console logs "Save resource". This should not happen when the edit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

[@ckosloski](https://github.com/ckosloski) answered this on [Github](https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/482#issuecomment-222696078):

> I think it's because your edit button does not specify a button type.
>   By default, the button type is submit. So you are clicking on the
>   button and it's submitting the form since it's a submit button. Try
>   adding `type="button"` to your edit button.

Adding this solved it, as you can see from the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/15365/).